# second row cannot updated in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I create one page were it fetch data from register page. People can send request to that id. For that I put request send button. If user click that button prompt box appear and have to enter subject.

Now my problem is the subject enter is only save for first row. It doesn't support for second row. Second row id,user id and friend id only updated.

I hope you guys can help me to identify my fault.

Thanks again

This my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myid'];
$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','learning_malaysia');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutor_register INNER JOIN tutorskill ON tutor_register.register_ID = tutorskill.register_ID ORDER BY 
tutor_register.register_ID='".$_SESSION['myid']."'desc";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Resuming</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
    if (subject != null){
        document.getElementById("subject").value= subject;
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{      
        $register_ID=$row["register_ID"];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $profile = $row['profile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $address=$row['address'];
        $gender=$row['gender'];
         $main_subject=$row["main_subject"];
         $subject_add=$row["subject_add"];
        $rate_main=$row["rate_main"];
        $rate_add=$row["rate_add"];
        $qualification=$row["qualification"];
        ?>
        <table><form method="post">
        <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td height="230"><img src='<?php echo $profile;?>'width="200" height="200"/>&nbsp;</td><td><td></td></td>
        <td class="data" width="800"><strong>Username:</strong>  <?php echo $username;?></br>
        <strong>Address:</strong>  <?php echo $address;?></br>
        <strong>Gender:</strong><?php echo $gender;?></br>
         <strong>Main Subject:</strong><?php echo $main_subject  ;?></br>
         <strong>Subject Added: </strong><?php echo $subject_add;?></br>
         <strong>Main Subject Rate:</strong> <?php echo $rate_main;?></br>
        <strong> Added Subject Rate:</strong><?php echo $rate_add; ?></br>
         <strong>Qualification:</strong> <?php echo $qualification; ?></td>
           <?php 
         if($register_ID == $_SESSION['myid']){
                ?>
                <td><label>Your Profile</label></td>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>

                 <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> 
                 <td><button class='friendBtn unfriend'  name="" data-type="unfriend">Unfriend</button>
                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />
                 <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" data-uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ;?>/>
                 <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php 
                     if($register_ID == $_SESSION['friend_id'] && $_SESSION['status'] == "yes" ) {     
                     echo "Request Sent";
                     }
                     else { 
                     echo "Add Friend";
                     }
                     ?>"  /></td>     </form>

 </tr>
</div>
</table></form> 
<?php
            }
}
}?>


</body>
</html>

 <?php


if(isset($_POST['subject']) and $_POST['id']) {
$user_id = $_SESSION['myid'];
$friend_id = $_POST['id'];
$status = "yes";
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$sql="INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,subject,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','yes','$subject','$friend_id') ";

            if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                          $_SESSION['status']="yes";
                          $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
                         $_SESSION['friend_id']=$friend_id;
                         $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            } else {}
                              }





?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 1st row and 2nd row?

Comment: what do you mean by **Now my problem is the subject enter is only save for first row. It doesn't support for second row. Second row id,user id and friend id only updated.** by this. Can you tell us little bit more

Comment: yeah ill explain you, the thing is once i insert it can insert in database for first row id only and other id all cannot been inserted.- Sudharshan Nair

Comment: Sunny Bhadana - i put add friend button for each fetch row id from registration page which is link to subject prompt box,after i enter subject and press ok the button will change to request  sent. here my problem is the subject can insert for first row id only and whenever i choose second row id's send request , it bring to prompt box and after i enter subject it shows request sent but once open database it never inserted there..that is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code generates several forms, each with a hidden input field with the id "subject". When your JavaScript tries to find the element using `document.getElementById("subject")`, it will always find the first one.

To fix this, you could pass the correct **form** DOM element as a parameter to `myFunction()`, and use that to set the value of the subject field.

To pass the form, simply use `this.form`:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this.form)" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="xx" />
```

And then use it like this:

```
function myFunction(form){
    var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
    if (subject != null){
        form['subject'].value= subject;
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

Here is the final code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myid'];
$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','learning_malaysia');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutor_register INNER JOIN tutorskill ON tutor_register.register_ID = tutorskill.register_ID ORDER BY 
tutor_register.register_ID='".$_SESSION['myid']."'desc";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Resuming</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<script>
function myFunction(form){
    var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
    if (subject != null){
        form['subject'].value= subject;
        form.submit();
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{      
        $register_ID=$row["register_ID"];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $profile = $row['profile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $address=$row['address'];
        $gender=$row['gender'];
        $main_subject=$row["main_subject"];
        $subject_add=$row["subject_add"];
        $rate_main=$row["rate_main"];
        $rate_add=$row["rate_add"];
        $qualification=$row["qualification"];
        ?>
        <table><form method="post">
        <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td height="230"><img src='<?php echo $profile;?>'width="200" height="200"/>&nbsp;</td><td><td></td></td>
        <td class="data" width="800"><strong>Username:</strong>  <?php echo $username;?></br>
        <strong>Address:</strong>  <?php echo $address;?></br>
        <strong>Gender:</strong><?php echo $gender;?></br>
        <strong>Main Subject:</strong><?php echo $main_subject  ;?></br>
        <strong>Subject Added: </strong><?php echo $subject_add;?></br>
        <strong>Main Subject Rate:</strong> <?php echo $rate_main;?></br>
        <strong> Added Subject Rate:</strong><?php echo $rate_add; ?></br>
        <strong>Qualification:</strong> <?php echo $qualification; ?></td>
          <?php 
        if($register_ID == $_SESSION['myid']){
                ?>
                <td><label>Your Profile</label></td>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>

                <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> 
                <td><button class='friendBtn unfriend'  name="" data-type="unfriend">Unfriend</button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />
                <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" data-uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ;?>/>
                <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(this.form)" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="addfriend" value="<?php 
                    if($register_ID == $_SESSION['friend_id'] && $_SESSION['status'] == "yes" ) {     
                    echo "Request Sent";
                    }
                    else { 
                    echo "Add Friend";
                    }
                    ?>"  /></td>     </form>

</tr>
</div>
</table></form> 
<?php
            }
}
}?>


</body>
</html>

<?php


if(isset($_POST['subject']) and $_POST['id']) {
$user_id = $_SESSION['myid'];
$friend_id = $_POST['id'];
$status = "yes";
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$sql="INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,subject,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','yes','$subject','$friend_id') ";

            if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                          $_SESSION['status']="yes";
                          $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
                        $_SESSION['friend_id']=$friend_id;
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            } else {}
                              }





?>
```

As a side note, going forward you should really protect yourself from [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) (usually by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir anders...its work for me,, tq for the tips to prevent sql injection too..